# SQL-Oracle: Difficulties in resolving basic problems, part3

Tags: sql, oracle

So here it is...Produce a list of jobs for departments 10, 50, 20, in that order.
Display the job ID and department ID by using the set operators.
I have done this so far but i can't do the ordering properly(10,50,20), any ideas?...thanks

```
SELECT job_id, department_id
FROM (SELECT job_id, department_id
      FROM   employees
      WHERE  department_id IN ('10','20','50')
      INTERSECT
      SELECT job_id, department_id
      FROM   employees
      WHERE  department_id IN ('10','20','50')
      )    
GROUP BY department_id, job_id
ORDER BY COUNT(job_id);
```

the output is this:

```
job_ID      department_id

ST_CLERK     50
ST_MAN       50
MK_REP       20
SH_CLERK     50
AD_ASST      10
MK_MAN       20
```

Comment: why are you INTERSECT same query

Comment: And what is your expected output?

Comment: i'm at the very beginning with programming, never done it before, sql is my first language :D, so sorry for silly coding, i still have a lot to learn :)

Comment: expected output is ordering by 10 50 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to implement arbitrary ordering

```
ORDER BY (CASE department_id
               WHEN 10 THEN 1
               WHEN 50 THEN 2
               WHEN 20 THEN 3
               ELSE 4
           END) ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

As a note, you could also do `instr()`:

```
order by instr(',10,50,20,', ',' || department_id || ',')
```

The extra commas are to ensure that there are no problems with similar substrings ("110" and "10").  That is not a problem for these particular values, so you could do:

```
order by instr('10,50,20', department_id)
```